# Good design of dealing with the failure connection to server in objective-c?

Tags: ios

If  my app client wants to connect to server. However in a bad network status,it fails many times.. How to solve this problem ? A recursive request? By showing a UIAlertView with two choices: cancel or confirm to connect again,actually calling a recursive request manually? Or without notify the user , app request to connect to server at background? What's the good design..I am new to develop .. Appreciate for any idea/suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the AFNetworking library. It has good network reachability status checking. From AFNetworking documentation:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = manager.operationQueue;
[manager.reachabilityManager   setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
switch (status) {
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
        [operationQueue setSuspended:NO];
        NSLog(@"Connected!");
        break;
    case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
    default:
        NSLog(@"Not Connected!");
        [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
        break;
    }
}];

[manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```